# Pip error after changing from bash to zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, python, oh-my-zsh

So I recently changed from the `bash` shell to `zsh`.
However, I have some trouble when working with `python` specifically pip.
When I try

```bsh
pip list
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.main'
```

Doing `which pip` gives me `/home/marvin/.local/bin/pip`, So following a line I saw in my `bashrc` , I added this to `zshrc`

```
# adding packages installed via pip
export PATH="/home/marvin/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

I also restarted shell and machine just to give a try.
I am still not able to work with virtual environments with pip.
Could someone guide me on a solution to this?

**[Edit]**

So I did

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

and got it working globally. Unfortunately, I had to re-create my virtual environment. The hiccup though, switching between shells would mean a re-creation of an environment. there's gotta be a better way of doing this

Comment: Did you have some other `pip` or Python-related settings in your old `bash` init files tah may be relevant to how `pip` behaved under `bash`?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error message and it was an issue related to my `$PATH`.

Here's some troubleshooting steps.

You can view your path with `echo $PATH`.

`which pip` and `which python` should return the same location. Those commands search the directories in your `$PATH` to find the first location that contains the executable.

If you're using `pyenv`, `which pip` and `which python` will return the same "shims" directory but that doesn't necessarily mean the executables are being run from the same directory. In that case, use `pyenv which pip` and `pyenv which python`.

In my case, my $PATH had a `~/.local/bin/` directory that was being prepended when I ran inside tmux. `~/.local/bin/` had a `pip` executable but no `python` executable. So I was trying to use a `pyenv` version of Python but a `~/.local/bin/pip` version of pip.

edit to clarify:

If `which pip` and `which python` show different paths, or in the case of pyenv if `pyenv which pip` and `pyenv which python` show different paths, then that may be the problem.

The solution will depend on your environment so it's difficult to give a one-solution-fits-all answer.

Maybe your `$PATH` has `~/.local/bin` *before* `/usr/bin` and `~/.local/bin` has a `pip` executable but not a `python` executable. So your computer is finding `pip` in `~/.local/bin` but finding `python` in `/usr/bin`. In that case, you could delete the `pip` in `~/.local/bin` if you don't need it. Or you could update it to be a symlink to the pip in `/usr/bin` (assuming you have another `pip` executable there). Or you could add a symlink of `~/.local/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python`. Or you could update your `$PATH` so that it searches `/usr/bin` *before* searching `~/.local/bin`.

The solution is dependent on your environment, how you installed Python, which version you want to use, etc...

Comment: I got a `/home/marvin/.local/bin/pip ` and a `/bin/python` for `pyenv which ...`

Comment: Edited to clarify. In short: that they are different is what I think is the problem. Try doing whatever it takes to make those match and see if it fixes the issue. It's not easy for someone to say what you should do to make those match because it's very dependent on your particular environment.

Answer (score 0):

This weirdness may caused by some PATH and python/pip version differences.

I suggest to check the outputs of these commands, both in bash and zsh:

```
pip --version
python -m pip --version
pip2 --version
python2 -m pip --version
pip3 --version
python3 -m pip --version
```

As [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858) suggested, you need also check the init files like `.bashrc`. It depends... sometimes it's easier to diff the outputs of `set` in the zsh/bash environment. That diff is probably huge (1k lines or more) so its like looking for a needle in the haystack. Missing or changed variables (like PATH was) and PYTHONNOUSERSITE, PYTHONPATH and anything starts with PIP or contains PIP (or PY?) shell functions (as pip() { ... } ) may counts.

Comment: Tried that out, would not work on zsh as it does not recognize pip. Definitely works in bash. Check the updated question?